# R: Contour plot for each component of a fitted bivariate mixture

Tags: r, plot

(*Please note: I'm using R for only two days now.*)

---

I have a dataset [`data`](http://www.oa.uj.edu.pl/M.Tarnopolski/forR.csv) that looks like this:

```
plot(data, pch=20, xlim=c(-2,3), ylim=c(-1,2))
```

[image]

I'm using the [`mixsmsn`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixsmsn/index.html) package to fit a mixture of bivariate skew-normal distributions:

```
sn2 <- smsn.mmix(data, nu=3, g=2, get.init=TRUE, criteria=TRUE, group=TRUE, family="Skew.normal", error=1e-08, iter.max=10000)
```

I can plot it like this (why `pch=20` doesn't work?):

```
mix.contour(data, sn2, pch=20, xlim=c(-2,3), ylim=c(-1,2), levels=c(0.1,0.25,0.5))
```

[image]

How can I achieve the following?

I'd want to draw a contour separately for each component at half its height. That is, say it's a mixture distribution of the form `p f_1(x,y) + (1-p) f_2(x,y)` (`f_i` being the pdf of the _i_th skew-normal component); I'd want to draw (on a scatter plot) a contour of the `f_1` component at half its height, and a second contour related to `f_2` at half its height; I'd like the result to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`fMultivar`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fMultivar/index.html) package, I came up with this:

```
X <- data

sn2 <- smsn.mmix(X, nu=3, g=2, get.init=TRUE, criteria=TRUE, group=TRUE, family="Skew.normal", error=1e-08, iter.max=10000)

mu1 <- sn2$mu[[1]]
sigma1 <- sn2$Sigma[[1]]
alpha1 <- c(sn2$shape[[1]][1], sn2$shape[[1]][2])
p1 <- sn2$pii[[1]]

mu2 <- sn2$mu[[2]]
sigma2 <- sn2$Sigma[[2]]
alpha2 <- c(sn2$shape[[2]][1], sn2$shape[[2]][2])
p2 <- sn2$pii[[2]]

N <- 101
x <- seq(min(X[, 1]), max(X[, 1]), l=N)
y <- seq(min(X[, 2]), max(X[, 2]), l=N)
u <- grid2d(x, y)$x
v <- grid2d(x, y)$y
XY <- cbind(u, v)

Z1 <- matrix(p1*dmsn(XY, mu1, sigma1, alpha1), ncol=N)
Z2 <- matrix(p2*dmsn(XY, mu2, sigma2, alpha2), ncol=N)

c1 <- 0.5*max(Z1)
c2 <- 0.5*max(Z2)

plot(X, pch=20, xlim=c(-2,3), ylim=c(-1,2))

contour(x, y, Z1, add=TRUE, col="red",   lwd=3, levels=c(c1), labels="")
contour(x, y, Z2, add=TRUE, col="green", lwd=3, levels=c(c2), labels="")
```

[image]